# Prove f is continuous at any a

Tags: real-analysis

I am working with the function f that maps from the positive reals to the complex numbers such that f(xy) = f(x) + f(y). I have shown or was given that f is differentiable at 1, f'(1) = 1, f(1) = 0, f(1/x) = -f(x), and that f(x) - f(a) = ($\frac{x}{a}$-1)$\frac{f(\frac{x}{a})-f(1)}{\frac{x}{a}-1}$ for all x and a.

I am supposed to use the last part of that to prove that f is continuous at any a belonging to the positive reals and have been spinning my tires for some time now. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If the last identity holds then
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)+\lim_{x\to a}f(x/a)-f(1)=f(a)+\lim_{x\to1}f(x)-f(1).
$$
What can you say about $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)\,$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(a)$ and show that $g$ is continuous at $a$.

(You will have to patch a removable discontinuity first).